# Android super.setContentView() in a method causes error?

Tags: java, android

Why would calling super.setContentView()

in a method cause the android process to terminate unexpectedly?
but when I remove it it works fine?

```
package com.example.debuggingTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.*;



public class TestDebugingActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.start);

    ImageView start = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button signin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    signin.setOnTouchListener(this);
    start.setOnTouchListener(this);



  }

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Button signin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);


    register.setText(event.toString());
    signin.setText(String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()));


    if(event.getPointerCount() >= 3) {
        signin.setText("Working");

//
//THIS CAUSES THE ERROR
//
        super.setContentView(R.layout.linear);

    }

    return true;

}



}
```

Comment: Please post the logcat output of the exception. There's actually no point in calling `signin.setText("Working")` if you are changing the content view. If the call doesn't crash the app, the button will vanish from the screen.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  setContentView should only be called in onCreate.  Are you trying to switch to a totally different layout when they touch something?

Comment: yes correct a form when an image is touched..

Comment: 03-15 21:40:20.150: E/AndroidRuntime(4846): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I think, you can't call setContentView() from a listener like that. You either need to make your form into its own activity, or you need to implement something like ViewFlipper to be the parent for multiple Layouts.